# PHP кукиес не работают. Можно удалить php?

Tags: php

Не работают куки в PHP, имеем массив со всеми переводами текста: `$local` 
ассоциативный массив в котором ещё массивы выглядит это всё примерно так

```php
$local = array(
    'ru' => array(
        'title' => 'Название проекта',
        'authTitle' => 'Авторизация на проекте'
    ),
    'en' => array(
        'title' => 'Name project',
        'authTitle' => 'Sign in'
    )
);
```

По дефолту ключ страны равен предпочтением пользователя и выяснение кода страны выглядит примерно так:

```php
$localCode = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];

if (isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) {//эта х+етень почему то возвращает false то биж он считает что НЕТУ куки lang но сам куки есть (в браузере зачекал)
    $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
} else {
    $lang = $localCode[0] . $localCode[1];//$localcode вернёт несколько кодов страны через запятую и мы выберем 2 первых символа тем самым выберем самый предпочитаемый язык пользователя
}
```

То биж если есть куки то код страны равен этому куки, если его нет то код страны равен первому предпочтению пользователя

В итоге когда я создаю куки lang:

```php
session_start();

setcookie("lang", "en", time() + 3600);
```

Куки создаётся в браузере и принимает нужное значение, но когда я отдельном файле `local.php` я пытаюсь их использовать система считает что их просто нет
код с функцией выдачи нужного языка:

```php
function lang ($name) {

    global $local;

    global $lang;

    echo $local[$lang][$name];
}
```

вынесен в отдельный файл и при создании куки lang он не хочет менять язык

Теперь про некоторые детали:

1. Почему я сделал `global $local` и `$lang` вместо того что бы просто внести их в функцию. Ответ: имеется 2 функции которые дают нужный перевод и одна их них выводит этот перевод а другая возвращает его это нужно что бы я не писал миллион раз echo а когда нужно вернуть а не вывести просто применялась другая функция.
2. Я не знаю обязательно ли начинать сессию в файле но в начале файла есть

```php
session_start();
```

Ниже 3 картинки примеров кода как подключается `local.php` и сам код `local.php` в наглядности (его stackoverflow не хочет по красоте вставить)[image: Это способ подключения файла и пример его использование в виде функций][image: Функции][image: Массив текста]

Comment: Хоть не к теме, но всё же `$lang = $localCode[0] . $localCode[1]` => `$lang = trim(explode(",",$localCode)[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> когда я отдельном файле local.php я пытаюсь их использовать система считает что их просто нет

`setcookie()` задает `cookie`, которое будет передано клиенту вместе с другими `HTTP`-заголовками. Как и любой другой заголовок, `cookie` должны передаваться до того как будут выведены какие-либо другие данные скрипта (это ограничение протокола). Это значит, что в скрипте вызовы этой функции должны располагаться до остального вывода, включая вывод тегов `<html>` и `<head>`, а также пустые строки и пробельные символы.

**--->** После передачи клиенту `cookie` станут доступны через массив `$_COOKIE` при следующей загрузке страницы. Значения `cookie` также есть в `$_REQUEST`. **<---**

*Источник: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.setcookie.php

Ответ простой - смотрите, где у Вас что не соответствует - или приведите полный код, с которым можно было разбираться.

Comment: Я изменил немного вопрос, добавил наглядных картинок и setcookie создаётся в отдельном файле в котором нет заголовков

Comment: $_COOKIE -  'суперглобальная' или автоматическая глобальная переменная, и если она действительно была установлена ранее, то будет доступна - посмотрите настройки тестового браузера - возможно, у Вас режим отключения или стирания кук стоит. И еще - она должна быть сначала установлена, а потом доступна - если порядок нарушен, то если и устанавливается, то будет доступна при следующей перезагрузке страницы - ну, а если страница не перезагружается (ajax ) - то и не будет до реальной перезагрузки.

Comment: Поставьте в нужные файлы просмотр $_COOKIE  - и найдете, где затык.

Comment: Похоже нашёл, куки создаются в файле, который в папке и работают только внутри этой папки по этому когда я пытаюсь использовать куки на 1 директорию ниже он пишет что их нет

Comment: Это что-то не то - Вы на локале запускаете - что-то сервер чудит - сайт и есть папка, в которой множество других, и куки доставать до всех должны.

Comment: Там написано на форуме что куки создаются и доступны только для той папки в которой были созданы, для исправления нужно просто ещё 1 параметр добавить в функцию куки

Comment: То есть, вопрос Вы решили - вот и отлично!